# How to factor out cubic polynomial with constant term?

Tags: polynomials

My polynomial: $ 2400x^{3} - 9880 x^{2} - 266 x + 123 = 0 $

So far, I've tried to solve this polynomial with synthetic division, the [Wiki-How](https://www.wikihow.com/Factor-a-Cubic-Polynomial), and this [page](https://sciencing.com/factor-third-power-polynomials-7448769.html), but nothing seems to yield the solution of $ x = 0.1 $

Can somebody show me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring gives $2400x^{3} - 9880 x^{2} - 266 x + 123= \left( 10 x-1\right)  \left( 240 {{x}^{2}}-964 x-123\right)$ and thus one of the three roots is $x=\frac1{10}$.

I do not see an easy way of spotting this if you do not already know the solution, but the long division is not difficult:

```
           240 x^2 -  964 x   -  123
        _____________________________________ 
10x - 1 ) 2400 x^3 - 9880 x^2 -  266 x  + 123 
          2400 x^3 -  240 x^2
          ____________________
                   - 9640 x^2 -  266 x
                   - 9640 x^2 +  964 x
                   ___________________
                              - 1230 x  + 123
                              - 1230 x  + 123 
                              ===============
```

Comment: Note that in your long division it is $226$ rather than $266$!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yes - thank you (and an x^2 should have been x^3)

Answer (score 1):

The number $\frac{1}{10}$ is indeed a root of this polynomial.

The polynomial is equal to $(10 x - 1) (240 x^2 - 964 x - 123)$

You can also use Wolfram Alpha to factor/decompose your polynomial:

[Wolfram Alpha polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2400*x%5E3%E2%88%929880*x%5E2%E2%88%92266x%2B123)